# Using existing git submodule with ExternalProject_Add in CMake

Tags: git, cmake

My project is currently using `ExternalProject_Add` to obtain the source code of an external library. By default `ExternalProject_Add` downloads data from a URL: is it possible to point it to an existing directory, already downloaded by git with `git submodule init`, `git submodule update`... ?

Comment: Wouldn't the ````add_subdirectory()```` command help you with this?

Comment: @Geo as far as I understand, wtih `ExternalProject_Add` I can easily pass configuration options to the library I need to compile via `CMAKE_ARGS` and such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set the `SOURCE_DIR` argument without any additional download options.

> Source directory into which downloaded contents will be unpacked, or for non-URL download methods, the directory in which the repository should be checked out, cloned, etc. If no download method is specified, this must point to an existing directory where the external project has already been unpacked or cloned/checked out.

See the docs: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/ExternalProject.html